# include/config.h:5:10: fatal error: config/.h: no such file or directory

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

I'm new to u-boot and trying to build it for next defconfig

```
CONFIG_ARM=y
CONFIG_ARCH_SUNXI=y
CONFIG_MACH_SUN8IW20=y
CONFIG_SUNXI_GPIO_V2=y
#CONFIG_AXP_GPIO=y
CONFIG_SYS_CONFIG_NAME="sun8iw20p1"
CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEVICE_TREE="sun8iw20p1-soc-system"
CONFIG_CONSOLE_MUX=y
CONFIG_SUNXI_NECESSARY_REPLACE_FDT=y
CONFIG_RESERVE_FDT_SIZE=0x20000
CONFIG_PRE_CONSOLE_BUFFER=n
CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE=y
CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE=0x43000000
CONFIG_SUNXI_FDT_ADDR=0x41800000
CONFIG_SUNXI_MALLOC_LEN=0x3600000
```

but after

```
make
```

I'm getting error
**include/config.h:5:10: fatal error: config/.h: no such file or directory**

Can anyone help to overcome this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set "CONFIG_SYS_NAME" to an arbitrary string.  And if SUN8IW20 isn't really just something we should treat as "sun8i" you'll need to add a lot more information to arch/arm/mach-sunxi/Kconfig so that it's handled correctly.